# Flex, XML Descendents

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I want to get all xml elements (xml descendents) which have some attributes like:

```
<books>
    <book concept="rr" author="xx"/>
    <book concept="tt" />
    <book concept="yy" />
    <book concept="uu" author="xx"/>
</books>
```

I need to perform a xml descendent search for xml nodes with author attribute containing
results should be:

```
<book concept="rr" author="xx"/>
<book concept="uu" author="xx"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or with XML selectors:

```
var booksXML: XML = <books>
    <book concept="rr" author="xx"/>
    <book concept="tt" />
    <book concept="yy" />
    <book concept="uu" author="xx"/>
</books>

var haveAuthor:XMLList = booksXML.book.(attribute("author").length() > 0);
//booksXML.book.(@author) won't work
```

Answer (score 1):

This should answer your question:

```
var booksXML: XML = <books>
    <book concept="rr" author="xx"/>
    <book concept="tt" />
    <book concept="yy" />
    <book concept="uu" author="xx"/>
</books>

for each (var xmlBook: XML in booksXML.children())
{
    if (xmlBook.@author != undefined)
        trace(xmlBook.toXMLString());
}
```